# Better render in the preview

Tags: python, customization

I would like to know if it is possible to display the normal quality of an image in a preview.

I have an icon in 256 pixel, the result is nice.

[image]

When I see this icon in the preview, the render is far from that.

[image]

It seems that the preview shows a smaller version of the icon, so the render is not really good.

Thx for your help ;)

Comment: By the looks of it I would say that the icon is downscaled to 128x128 in the Blender UI. You should render in the resolution blender displays.

Comment: I tested in 128x128 and the result was worst than in 256x256.
It's like if the preview take the picture, downscale and then use it in 128x128.

I search also if it is possible to make the preview entirely visible in a popup.

Like this picture.
http://pitiwazou.com/screenshots/XnView_-_%5B%5ED261E74E5D74A85711D0EE55853479A110F08BA_2016-01-17_22-37-45.jpg

Comment: Maybe try user preferences/ system and up the dpi?